# Test Mongo connection at my vertx application startup

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I've currently needed to test my mongodb connection at application startup using [Vertx MongoDB Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/js/). But there's no option to do this in its docs. There's a heartbeat configuration properties but this approach only gives me logs. I need try and handle connection errors.

Any suggestions?

Thanx

Comment: How about sending a simple query and checking if it succeeds?

Comment: @tsegismont I already considered send a "SELECT 1" like query but my mongo knowledge are very limited. You mean a simple _find limit 1_ against my lightest collection should be an option?